# How to get a token for aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentity

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to use the go sdk to access coginto, and i'm not sure how to get a token, i'm creating my cogintoidentity with:

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials("-id-", "-secret-", "")
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
sess.Config.Credentials = creds
sess.Config.Region = aws.String("us-east-1")
sess.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors = aws.Bool(true)
svc := CP.New(sess) // CP == "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/cognitoidentityprovider"

log.Println(svc.ListUserPools(&CP.ListUserPoolsInput{MaxResults: aws.Int64(10)}))
```

But it returns `The security token included in the request is invalid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the pool's client id/secret, not my AWS's.